# How to display only the document titles on the index.html

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In my **sphinx-build** generated documents, the index page displays the `Document title` and `Section Title` links.

```
==============
Document Title
==============

Section Title
-----------------
```

I don't want the `Section Title` to be displayed on the index page,

so I changed the rst to use the subtitle formatting, but it still appears on the index page. How to resolve this problem?

```
==============
Document Title
==============

Section Title (Document Subtitle)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, setting the `maxdepth` to `1` (earlier it was `2`) on *index.rst* gives the desired behavior.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
```